# Loading PDF constant in flex mobile app

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, flash-builder, blackberry-playbook

I'm working on a project to make an app for the Blackberry Playbook using adobe builder, I want the app to make it easy to read pdf books (I'll embed the books in the app) I want to make bookmarks and make it look like a book.

So now I'm searching for some samples or advise which technology to use for this.

Comment: It sounds like you already chose a technology (Flex, PDF, Playbook).  Are you having problems?  I didn't think you could embed a PDF in a Flex app and display it as part of the app.

Comment: I didn't yet chosen which technology to use for the document's, it could be done using a database like sqlite, or xml or any other way I don't know.

Comment: the main thing i need is some sample to a similar project to help me get started

Comment: this site is a place to get answers to specific programming questions; not one to compare the merits of different technologies for specific projects.  I recommend you do your own research to evaluate options for your project; or hire a consultant to do it for you.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try my lock somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no practical options for displaying PDFs on the PlayBook in any way other than with the bundled Adobe Reader app.

Once the NDK is available this fall, that situation should change.

Comment: what is NDK if I may ask? - I know there's no good reader, that's why I want to make one... same is true with the file explorer there is no build in but there are plenty of good 3'rd party app's available.

Comment: The NDK is the "Native Development Kit", an SDK which will allow building apps using C++ and loadable libraries (DLLs, if you will).  That opens up the possibility to use any number of pre-existing free or commercial libraries that would enable this.